# lldb - How do I kill commands stuck in infinite loops

Tags: xcode, lldb

Simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere online and it's really frustrating.

Suppose I have this buggy code I'm trying to debug:

```
int myBug()
{
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

If I'm debugging this with LLDB and type `print myBug()` I get no result, ever (no surprises). However this means I can no longer debug because LLDB is stuck and cannot `continue`. Is there a way to kill the `print myBug()` command? So far the only workaround is quitting and restarting everything -- far from convient.

I'm using LLDB in Xcode 4.6.1 and I've trying a bunch of keystrokes like Ctrl+C, Ctrl+T, but nothing seems to work :(

Comment: I just hit the pause button.

Comment: @H2CO3: tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: @HotLicks there is no pause button. Only a play button and hitting it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: If it's a play button then your code has stopped already.

Comment: As a workaround, you can quit the process with Activity Monitor or, using the terminal, using `kill -3 pid`.

Comment: Dont write buggy code with inifinite loops. That would help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, from within Xcode there isn't an easy way to interrupt this expression evaluation.  If you're using command-line lldb, control-C will work as expected.  You can send a signal to your process, `killall -INT appname`.  You can give lldb a timeout for an expression evaluation, expressed in microseconds, so a five second timeout calling `myBug()` looks like

```
(lldb) expr -t 5000000 -- myBug()
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: breakpoint 1.1.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
(lldb)
```

You can file a bug report about this on Xcode at http://bugreport.apple.com/ if this is something that comes up in your workflow.